# What is the meaing of $ in (*ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async")

Tags: angular

```
<div id="search-component">
    <h4>Hero Search</h4>

    <input #search Box id="searchbox"  
    ( keyup )="search( searchBox.value)" />

    <ul class="search-result">
        <li *ng For="let hero of heroes$ | a sync" >
            <a router Link="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
                {{hero.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

- What is the meaning of $ in this code?
- What is the use of $ with ngFor tag?

Answer (score 5):

`heroes$` is just a name of a variable.

It is just a convention to name variable with dollar sign at the end when the type of the variable is an `Observable`.

Comment: can i am change the variable name without $..code work same as...?

Comment: If you change it in both places, the components class and the view, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have a meaning.
It just means that `*ngFor` should iterate the values emitted by the observable field or getter named `heroes$`

It's common that developers suffix fields or getters that return an observable with `$` to indicate just that.

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;
```

The name could just be `heroes` as well.